# jquery mobile flipswitch chcekbox always on

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have a checkbox flip switch like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="control_name[]"/>
  <label for="flip-checkbox-4">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="control_name_switch[]" id="flip-checkbox-4" checked=""/>
</form>
```

the form is read with this php code:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $controlname = $_POST['control_name'];
  $controlstate = $_POST['control_name_switch'];
  $program = $_POST['program'];
  $i = 0;
  $ctrlSize = sizeof($controlname);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $ctrlSize; $i++) {
    if (empty($_POST['control_name_switch'])) {
        $controlstate[$i] = "&nbsp;";
    } else {
        $controlstate[$i] = "checked";
    }
  }
```

When I read the post in a php, I get it to be always "on" even if i have clicked it and turned it off. Please help.

Comment: it's better to add that code to your post. it'll help others understand the problem.

Comment: is it ok now. ? Can it be read? pls help. stuck at it.